# xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token) in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am trying to open an XML file using `ElementTree` but an error occurred:

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

And here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def main():
    tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
    print 'parsing Success!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You are getting a parsing error, so this question is worthless unless we can see the `xml` you are trying to parse.

Comment: I don't understand your msg.

Comment: We need to see the content of the file `test.xml`.

Comment: I attached xml contents. this is a PDML file. thanks.

Comment: And now you have removed the XML content. What was the point of that?

Comment: what was the offending token?

Comment: downvoted for having removed the xml content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [XML format rules](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) state that you have to have one root element. Your document has two of them, `pdml` and `packet`. I'm not familiar with PDML, but a XML parser probably will choke on that.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the proper encoding ie:

```
etree.parse('test.xml', etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the closing `</pdml>` tag at the end of the xml file.